# ios tableview : rows are less than the count returned by numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view in which the method numberOfRowsInSection returns correctly as desired by the user. But actual number of rows appearing is less than the number returned by numberOfRowsInSection. Cells are not static. I have not set any restriction on number of rows. I am using a storyboard, this may be a storyboard issue. Any leads?

Code snippet:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
if(self.timelineModel){
    NSMutableArray *sectionArray =  self.timelineModel[self.stepperValue];
    NSLog(@"no of rows : %lu",(unsigned long)sectionArray.count);
    return sectionArray.count;
}
else{
    return 1;
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
LTTimeLineTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell !=nil){
    //some code
}

//some code
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
[cell.rowCollView reloadData];
NSLog(@"row number : %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
return cell;
}
```

The logs which appear are:

```
log 1: 
2014-11-21 17:28:25.937 xx[89937:1095174] no of rows : 6
2014-11-21 17:28:25.938 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 0
2014-11-21 17:28:25.939 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 1
2014-11-21 17:28:25.939 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 2
2014-11-21 17:28:25.940 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 3

log 2:
2014-11-21 17:07:54.932 xx[89937:1095174] no of rows : 5
2014-11-21 17:07:54.933 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 0
2014-11-21 17:07:54.933 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 1
2014-11-21 17:07:54.934 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 2
2014-11-21 17:07:54.937 xx[89937:1095174] row number : 3
```

Comment: what is "self.timelineModel" and what is "self.timelineModel[self.stepperValue]" returning?

Comment: What happens if you try to scroll down?  Does it scroll at all, or bounce?  If you programmatically scroll down to row 5/6, does that work?

Comment: What is rowCollView and why do you need to reloadData?

Comment: Sorry folks, false alarm. Something was wrong with my simulator due to which it was not scrolling down and hence the delegate method was not being called. This lead me to believe that the row is not formed at all. But when I ran the code on an ipad its working fine with scrolls,etc. Anyways, thanks for your valuable inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.

Rows in UITableView is loaded smart, there are loaded only those rows that are visible on the screen, other will be loaded after scrolling.

This is because `alloc` (creating object in memory) is costly. Because of this iOS create only few cells and then recycle them.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in this case not even scrolling down is helping. Even after scroll, no extra row is loaded

Comment: But is it true that only first three cells are visible at first load of table ? Because it is interesting from your log that always return 3 cells no mather what is number of cells. Is it possible that numberOfRows are called again with different number or that delegate is changed?